# Extjs to call a RESTful webservice

Tags: ajax, web-services, extjs, rest

I am trying to make a RESTful webservice call using Extjs. Below is the code i am using:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({ url: incomingURL ,
   method: 'POST',
   params: {param1:p1, param2:p2},
   success: function(responseObject){
     var obj = Ext.decode(responseObject.responseText);
     alert(obj);
   },
   failure: function(responseObject){
     var obj = Ext.decode(responseObject.responseText);
     alert(obj);
   }
});
```

but it does not work, the request is sent using OPTIONS method instead of POST.

I also tried to do the same thing using below code but result is the same:

```
var conn = new Ext.data.Connection();
conn.request({
  url: incomingURL,
  method: 'POST',
  params: {param1:p1, param2:p2},
  success: function(responseObject) 
  {
    Ext.Msg.alert('Status', 'success');
  },
  failure: function(responseObject) 
  {
    Ext.Msg.alert('Status', 'Failure');
  }
});
```

But when i tried to do the same thing using basic ajax call ( using the browser objects directly i.e. XMLHttpRequest() or ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")) it works fine and i get the response as expected.

Can anyone please help me, as i am not able to understand what i am doing wrong with extjs ajax call?

Comment: 4 spaces indent for block code.  Backticks for inline code.

Comment: I see no obvious reason why this would emit an OPTIONS instead of a POST. What do the variables `incomingURL`, `p1`, and `p2` look like?

Comment: The snippet you provided (at least the first one) looks OK to me. I use it every day. What browser do you use? Do you use Firebug?

Comment: Agreed, the code looks fine. What is the value of incomingURL?

Comment: The value of incoming url is https://mymachine.com:443/cas/v1/tickets and the value of params is:  {username:p1,password:p2} where p1 and p2 can take values like "vivek" and p2 like "testpwd". 
We have tried to run this code on IE7 and Firefox 3.5.5.
With or without enabling firebug this behavior is same.

Comment: We are trying to make ajax call between two different hosts - eg: abc.mycompany.com making ajax calls to def.mycompany.com

Comment: I think this will explain what you're seeing: https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTTP_access_control See the part on preflighting requests.

Answer (score 2):

You can't make a standard AJAX call between domains. The URL for Ext.Ajax.request should be a relative one (relative to the script's origin).

If you want to do cross-domain calls, use a ScriptTagProxy or such.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is exactly because of the reason ob1 and Chuck Hinson described.

I have an RESTful service, wich is running on Tomcat.

And i made a static client(no deployed to Tomcat) using ExtJs with Json reader.
I just made an html page with ExtJs integrated consuming REST service like url: http://localhost:8080/service/invoices/

And all the time ExtJs was making OPTIONS request, not GET or POST even if i was setting them as being used methods. The problem is this security feature, because Client is not the part of same application and i am doing AJAX call between domains.

As soon as i put my client to my Web application and deployed to Tomcat and started using relative calls it started working.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want cross-domain request, please remove the website prefix 'http://website' from propery `url` of ajax proxy.