# Reload JsonStore making OPTIONS request

Tags: javascript, ajax, firefox, extjs

Why is a call to the reload method of a JsonStore making an OPTIONS request to the server?  When running under IE, the reload makes a POST request, but under FF an OPTIONS request.

Can I prevent FireFox (or ExtJS) from making an OPTIONS request?

Comment: There was this recent related question on stack overflow, which remained unanswered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1826671/

Comment: Might be a bug in Ext.  You'll probably have better luck following up in the forums.

Comment: I agree; I'll submit there also.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think my problem [involves FF 3.5](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2009/07/cross-site-xmlhttprequest-with-cors/).